# Django 1.4: How can I access request object in inclusion_tag

Tags: django, django-templates

Code

```
@register.inclusion_tag('template.html', takes_context=True)
def include_client_side_bar(context):
    return {
        'STATIC_URL': settings.STATIC_URL,
        }
```

My code is will be something like this, I want to access request.user object inside this function, but I can't get it.

In the debugger, I can see these variables.
[image]

As far as I can recall, I have made this successfully in django 1.3, did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've included the [request context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting, and that your view is rendered with a [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request).

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I did have the request in my template context processor tuple. For the view, I have used the TemplateView, and I did not overwrite the get function, only have one line to specify the template name, would this get function uses RequestContext?

Comment: The template view,  and other generic views do use `RequestContext`. I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions.  Hope you can get it working.

Comment: Looks like my debugger has issue with everything Lazy.

Answer (score 1):

try with `request = context.get('request', None)` if request key doesn't exists assign None value.

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

**Update:**

Also you can pass user to inclusion_tag, with something like this

```
# In your template_tag
@register.inclusion_tag('template.html', takes_context=True)
def include_client_side_bar(context, user):
    if user:
         pass # do something
    return {
        'STATIC_URL': settings.STATIC_URL,
    }

# in your template
{% include_client_side_bar user=request.user %}
```